# how to add two variables to URL in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

I want to add two variables to URL in JSP

```
<a href="buyOrSell.do?symbol=<%=trade.getSymbol()%>&mktPrice="<%=trade.getCurrentMktPrice()%>>Buy</a>
```

ex - http://loclhost:8080/myProj/buyOrSell.do?symbol=anySymbol&mktPrice=price

but I am not able to get second variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you had a quote mark placed wrong in your code. Test the line below instead

```
<a href="buyOrSell.do?symbol=<%=trade.getSymbol()%>&mktPrice=<%=trade.getCurrentMktPrice()%>">Buy</a>
```

Comment: Glad to help, if you found the answer useful, feel free to mark it as "answer" :)

Comment: can accept any answer after 10 minutes, so i was waiting to mark it, thnx for ur fast response    :)